# Trouble passing an IO::File handle to a Perl class

Tags: perl, oop

If I pass it as an argument I get the error:

'Can't locate object method "getline" via package "Bad" at Bad.pm line 27.'

But if I insert it in the module it works.
This is the boiled down code. bad.pl uses the module Bad.pm. Set $CAUSE_ERROR to see the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# This is bad.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::File;
use Bad;    # use the bad module "Bad.pm"

&Main();

sub Main {
    my $filename = "bad.pl";
    warn "About to parse '$filename'\n";
    my $MyWord = Bad->new();   # Create a new object.

    my $io = IO::File->new($filename, "r");

    #####################
    my $CAUSE_ERROR  = 1;   # Set to 0 it does NOT cause an error. Set to 1 it DOES.
    #####################

    if($CAUSE_ERROR ) {
        $MyWord->Parse($MyWord, $io);
    } else {
        $MyWord->{fd} = $io;
        $MyWord->Parse($MyWord);
    }
}
```

This is Bad.pm

```
package Bad;
# This is Bad.pm

use warnings;
use strict;

sub new {
    my ($class, $args) = @_;
    my $self = {
        fd => undef,
    };
    return bless($self, $class);       # Changes a function to a class
}

sub Parse {
    my ($MyWord, $io) = @_;

    if(defined($MyWord->{fd})){
        # WORKS
        $io = $MyWord->{fd};
        while ( defined(my $inputline = $io->getline) ) {
            print "${inputline}";
        }
    } else {
        # FAILS
        while ( defined(my $inputline = $io->getline) ) {
            print "${inputline}";
        }
    }
}
1;
```

Using Perl v5.22.3 under Cygwin.
Originally I had Bad.pm in a sub directory but I simplified it.
Thank you for you time.

Comment: OOPS! I think that I see my problem. I should call it just as $MyWord->Parse($io); After looking at if for days I see it right after I post it.

Comment: When that happens, it's typically referred to as [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :)

Comment: I suggest a good read on classes. (0) Nothing is passed to your constructor. If you want an object per filehandle, pass it in `new`. (If not then `fd` shouldn't be part of data. (1) In ctor you assign `undef`? If you pass fd then `fd => $fd`, in your case `fd => $args`. (But that's a bad name -- it takes _one argument_).  Then there's data in the class and `$MyWord->{fd}` is fine (without having to pass fh to the method, too).  (2) The "good" case works in a very bad way -- it directly assigns to class internals, fixing the error in the constructor.

Comment: Are you using *ctor* as an abbreviation of *constructor*? I have never seen that before. Also, could you recommend where the OP might "read on classes" where he can find the advice you give here?

Comment: @Borodin  Right, good point, thank you.  I was contemplating writing up something for them so didn't add references.   The `ctor` can be run into in (loose) C++ exchanges (probably elsewhere, I don't recall).

Comment: Standard, and good, documents: tutorial [perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) and reference [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) on object-oriented work in Perl, [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) for modules (a class is a package), and a tutorial [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for references.  Also, there is a lot written around, from tutorials to informative SO posts.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize errors in the posted code: The class name is passed to the constructor behind the scenes, as is the object to methods; we *do not* supply them.  We do pass the filehandle to `new`, so that it is assigned to object's data and it can thus be used by methods in the class.

Here is a basic example.  I try to stick to the posted design as much as possible.  This does not do much of what is needed with I/O objects, but is rather about writing a class in general.

The class is meant to process a file, having been passed a filehandle for it.  We expect to have one filehandle per object. Since we get it open the reponsibility to close it is left to the caller.

**script.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';    
use IO::File;

use ProcessFile;

my $filename = shift || $0;         # from command line, or this file    
say "About to parse '$filename'";    
my $io = IO::File->new($filename, "r") or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

my $word = ProcessFile->new($io);   # Create a new object, initialize with $io
$word->parse();
# OR, by chaining calls
#my $word = ProcessFile->new($io)->parse();

say "Have ", ProcessFile->num_objects(), " open filehandles";    

$io->close;
```

The package file **ProcessFile.pm**

```
package ProcessFile;

use warnings;
use strict;
use Carp qw(croak);
use Scalar::Util qw(openhandle);

# Example of "Class" data and methods: how many objects (open filehandles)
our $NumObjects;
sub num_objects  { return $NumObjects }
sub DESTROY      { --$NumObjects }

sub new {
    my ($class, $fh) = @_;   # class name, arguments passed to constructor    
    # To also check the mode (must be opened for reading) use Fcntl module
    croak "No filehandle or not open or invalid " if not openhandle $fh;

    my $self = { _fh => $fh };  # add other data that may make sense
    bless $self, $class;        # now $self is an object of class ProcessFile

    ++$NumObjects;
    return $self;
}

sub parse {
    my ($self, @args) = @_;  # object, arguments passed to method (if any)

    # Filehandle is retrieved from data, $self->{_fh}
    while ( defined(my $inputline = $self->{_fh}->getline) ) {
        print $inputline;
    }

    # Rewind before returning $self (or not, depending on design/@args)
    # Can do more here, set some data etc, as needed by class design
    seek $self->{_fh}, 0, 0;
    return $self;
}

1;
```

A few comments on the above code follow.  Let me know if more would be helpful.

*Class* data and methods don't belong to any one object, and are used for purposes that relate to the class as a whole (for example, to track all objects in play).

The `DESTROY` method runs when an object is destroyed, for example when it goes out of scope.  Here we need it in order to decrease the count of existing objects.  Try: place the code creating an object in a block `{ ... };` and see what count we get after the block.

We use `openhandle` from [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html) to test whether the filehandle is open.  We should really also test whether it is open for *reading*, since that is the fixed purpose of the class, using [Fcntl](http://perldoc.perl.org/Fcntl.html).

In the sole, example method `parse` we read out the file and then rewind the filehandle, before returning the object.  That is a placeholder for saving and/or setting the state for repeated use. What is done depends on the purpose and design of the class, and can be controlled by arguments.

Documentation: tutorial [perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) and reference [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) on object-oriented work in Perl, [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) for modules (a class is firstly a package), and a tutorial [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for references.

There are also many informative SO posts around, please search.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize:

```
$MyWord->Parse($MyWord, $io);
```

Given that `$MyWord` is a reference blessed into the `Bad` class (i.e, it's an instance of `Bad`), this calls `Bad::Parse` with the arguments `($MyWord, $MyWord, $io)`. That is, it behaves as if you'd called:

```
Bad::Parse($MyWord, $MyWord, $io)`.
```

However, `Bad::Parse()` is written to expect the arguments `($MyWord, $io)`, so `$io` gets set to the second `$MyWord`, and `Bad::Parse()` throws an error when it tries to call `$io->getline` because the `Bad` module doesn't implement that method.

The fix is simple:

1. Call the function as `$MyWord->Parse($io)`.
2. Change the variable name for the first argument in `Bad::Parse()` from `$MyWord` to `$self`. This isn't strictly *necessary* -- you can technically call this variable whatever you want -- but it's conventional, and will make your code much more readable to other Perl programmers.